# Using Auto Layout to distribute views uniformly in a superview

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've laid out this view hierarchy in IB (Xcode 6.3.1):

[image]

I would like to use Auto Layout (FYI: I am new to Auto Layout) to distribute the subviews horizontally (their widths should *always* be equal to each other).

I'd really appreciate any pointers... the constraints I've added thus far have not kept the widths of the subviews equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add these constraints:

- width of green == width of white
- width of white == width of gray
- leading space of green (to superview) == 8
- horizontal space between green and white == 8
- horizontal space between white and gray == 8
- trailing space of gray (to superview) == 8

And you'll be good to go.

No need to specify that width of green == width of gray, they are already related to width of white, that'd be redundant, and autolayout hates redundancy.

Comment: Quick followup: do I add the "horizontal space between green and white" using the Pin menu? (thank you)

Comment: I usually right-click-and-drag (or ctrl-drag) from green to white, which pops up a menu from which I select "horizontal spacing". By using the Pin menu you're not quite sure of who the neighbor is in each direction.